# Intercept null ResponseBody before marshalling response

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I've got multiple controllers for RESTful endpoints which currently return `null` if there's no resource at the endpoint. For instance,

```
@RequestMapping(method = ReqeustMethod.GET, value = "{id}")
@ResponseBody
public MyResource get(@PathVariable final Long id) {
    return this.myService.get(id); // returns null if bad id
}
```

I want to return a specific, different resource to the client (`ErrorResource`) when there's no `MyResource` with the given id. I know I can do that with a separate method with `@ExceptionHandler`, such as:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "{id}")
@ResponseBody
public MyResource get(@PathVariable final Long id) {
    final MyResource myResource = this.myService.get(id);
    if (myResource == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return myResource;
}

@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorResource notFoundException(
        final HttpServletRequest request,
        final NotFoundException exception) {

    final ErrorResource errorResource = new ErrorResource();
    errorResource.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
    errorResource.setDeveloperMessage("No resource found at " + request.getRequestURL());
    return errorResource;
}
```

And that's nice. But what I'd really like to be able to do is have some kind of interceptor that figures out for me that whenever an API method is returning a `null` `@ResponseBody`, it should instead run the logic in my `notFoundException()` method. That will make all my controller methods a little cleaner. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I think you may be looking for `HandlerInterceptor`.

Comment: @chrylis I did see that. `preHandle()` is too early, `postCompletion()` is too late. `postHandle()` gives me a `ModelAndView`. What do I do with that? Check for null and throw the exception? Rewrite the contents of the `Model` part of `ModelAndView`?

Comment: You could make the service throw the exception and stick to exceptions (moving the `@ExceptionHandler` in a base controller class)

Comment: @RC. I might be able to convince the owner of the service layer that throwing an exception indicating not found is preferable to returning null. Let's assume for the sake of this question that I can't. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a job for Spring's `HttpMessageConverter`.

You can write your own converter by implementing `HttpMessageConverter<T>` interface.

In your case I would implement a converter of `HttpMessageConverter<MyResource>` with a null check on the `MyResource` instance in the `write` method. If the `MyResource` instance is null, then build and write your `ErrorResource` instance.

Here is an example:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;

public class MyResourceConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<MyResource> {

    // a real message converter that will respond to ancillary methods and do the actual work
    private HttpMessageConverter<Object> delegateConverter;

    public MyResourceConverter(HttpMessageConverter<Object> delegateConverter){
        this.delegateConverter = delegateConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return delegateConverter.canRead(clazz, mediaType) && MyResource.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return delegateConverter.canWrite(clazz, mediaType) && MyResource.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public MyResource read(Class<? extends MyResource> clazz,
            HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException,
            HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return (MyResource) delegateConverter.read(clazz, inputMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(MyResource t, MediaType contentType,
            HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException,
            HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        Object result = null;
        if(t == null){
            result = // build your ErrorResource here
        }else{
            result = t;
        }
        delegateConverter.write(result, contentType, outputMessage);

    }
}
```

Note that this converter needs to be registered in your Spring configuration.
The configuration class must extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and override the `configureMessageConverters` method, like:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    // Here we add our custom-configured HttpMessageConverters.
    // yourDelegateConverter may be a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter instance for example
    converters.add(new EmployeeConverter(yourDelegateConverter));
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

---

References (from official Spring documentation):

- [HTTP Message conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-message-conversion)
- [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html)
- [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html)